# Querying objects that is created minutes ago

Tags: python, django, django-models

So , We have a model called Status.
Also we have a Datetimefield in it and we add the auto_now_add=True in the model.
But the question is how can i query and find the objects that is created only two minutes ago ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `DateTimeField` is named `created_at`, you can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Status.objects.filter(created_at__gte=Now() - timedelta(minutes=2))
```

Comment: But i have this error : Cannot resolve keyword 'created_at' into field. Choices are: code, id, is_used, phone, start_time, user, user_id

Comment: @Alirezajavanpour: as said in the answer, it should use the `DateTimeField`. If you named this differently, like `start_time`, then it is `start_time__` instead of `created_at__`.